# gitlab ci not fired on commit

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a problem with one project on gitlab which is not firing ci build.

#### To explain my situation

I have Gitlab (GIT) working perfectly with 5 projects. Then I have Gitlab CI (CI) with four projects hooked from GIT. 3 of projects builds are fired on commit correctly but one does not.

#### What I have done

I imported the project as any other. If it didn't work I tried to remove ti and add it again but still nothing. Keys are set correctly in GIT. I tried to reboot server. And I cannot find any error in log files.
It still writes no bilds in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that. It was caused by bad protocol in GIT config.
I have both GIT and CI on https and in GIT project -> settings -> services -> gitlab ci -> there was http:// in Project url